# Javascript onClick prompt boxes?

Tags: javascript

How do I change that prompt box script into an onClick prompt?

```
<script> 
var name = prompt("What's Your Name");
var name1 = function (name) {
confirm("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};
name1(name)
</script>
```

please keep the script as it is, since this is the only way I could understand it.

Comment: You're asking us to show you how to change something to make it work, while simultaneously telling us to keep it the same.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the click event?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick

Answer (score 0):

You'd first need to use a html element to hook the onClick event to, let's use a plain button here:

```
<input type="button" onClick="name1(name);" value="Confirm Test" />
```

and pass on the function you created to the event.

These events can take in javascript blocks of code and execute it when the event arises, I'd also recommend taking a look at the specs like the one @David is suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Is a **best practice** add the "behavior" in a external JavaScript file and **NOT** like a *HTML attribute*.

For do that, just add the follow JavaScript code (in a external file):

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() { /* code */ }
```

Where the markup is:

```
<button id="button" type="submit">Click me!</button>
```

For "linking" that JavaScript code in your HTML page, just add the file with your code in the `script` element:

```
<script src="Your relative path (or absolute if you want)"></script>
```

Speaking of best practices, add the `script` element before the *body close tag*; **NOT** in the `head` element. With this way you'll avoid that the render of the page have to wait for the load of the JS files.

Here's an example: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/leoMestizo/DkmeQ/1/)

**BTW**, you don't need to create all those variables:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    confirm("Great to see you," + " " + prompt("What's Your Name"));
};
```